# It it right way to user a global QObject for cross signal/slot forward

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject

My situation is, a big Qt project with many QWidget communication requirement.

For example, I've a QPushButton **B** and a QLabel **L**, I need to click thd button **B** to show some text on label **L** or hide it, etc. But the problem is neither of them can get each other's object pointer, because both of them located in a deep QWidget tree, maybe their grandgrandgrand parent widget was sibling, what ever.

So my option, is creating a global unique QObject, just for singal/slot forwad,like this:

```
class GlobalForward: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GlobalForward():QObject(null) {}
signal:
    void SigForwardButton(bool toggle);

}

GlobalForward* gForwardObj;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv[]);

    gForwardObj = new GlobalForward();

    QWidget w;
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(&w);

    QWidget m;
    QLabel* label = new QLabel(&m);

    w.show();
    m.show();

    connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, gForwardObj, &GlobalForward::SigForwardButton);
    connect(gForwardObj, &GlobalForward::SigForwardButton, label, &QWidget::hide);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Actually, the **button** and the **label** are so faraway that they cannot see each other. I want to use **GlobalForward** to concat the singnal to make it work . Further more, it can forwad QEvent silmiarly.

What I want to know is, is this way properly solved my problem, and what's the **disadvantage** of it. Also, any better solution will be appropriate, thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using `QAction`? I'd suggest having some global object that contains actions and then you would only register appropriate action to given button...

Comment: It's ok. Use it.